# Composer PSR-4 PHPUnit class not found in same directory

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I have the following project structure

```
src/
   ├─ MyPackage/
               ├─ MySDK.php
               └─ SDKHelper.php
test/
    ├─ MySDKTest.php
    └─ TestUtils.php
composer.json
composer.lock
```

My composer.json file looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyPackage\\": "src/MyPackage"
    }
}
```

Everything worked great, and `MySDKTest.php` unit tests were passing, until I tried adding some utility methods to a third file, `TestUtils.php`. When I try to call `TestUtils::utilityMethod()` from `MySDKTest.php`, phpunit complains that the class `TestUtils` is not found.

I've been reading about adding an autoload-dev key, variations whereof I have tried, but so far, it appears that nothing is working. I should clarify that I am able to use `MySDK` and `SDKHelper` methods inside `MySDKTest`. `MySDKTest.php` looks like this when it works:

```
use MyPackage\MySDK;

class MySDKTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testPackage() {
        $sdk = new MySDK();
        $sdk->exampleMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: For a good question, you should always mention what exactly you tried, that didn't work. This will make it easier to spot your error. Don't write *I've been reading about adding an autoload-dev key, variations whereof I have tried*, show at least one example that you think should have done the job. Also show the code that cannot be loaded, not the code that already works, i.e. we need the `TestUtils.php` content, not `MySDKTest.php`.

Comment: Hey @Sven, I forgot about this question. As it turns out, I was actually doing everything right. Running `composer.phar install` again generated an updated autoload.php, which resolved the issue. I will add the `autoload-dev` configuration I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty simple. Composer's PSR-4 autoloader just defines a mapping from a namespace to a folder.

Are your tests namespaced correctly? It looks like they're not since you have a `use` at the top of your test class. If `MySDK` is in the namepace `MyPackage` (fully qualified `MyPackage\MySDK`), I would expect `MySDKTest` to also be in the `MyPackage` namespace at `MyPackage\MySDKTest`. It doesn't have to be that way - you could put the tests in a different namespace if you prefer.

Regardless, the reason it's not working is you didn't register the test folder with the autoloader. The way it looks like your stuff is currently set up, your autoloader config should look like this:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "MyPackage\\": ["src/MyPackage/", "test/"] }
    }
}
```

Also you'd need to change `use MyPackage\MySDK;` to `namespace MyPackage;` in your test class.

---

**Note**

Your folder structure is a little weird. I would expect `test` to match `src`. So it would be like this:

```
test/
    ├─ MyPackage/
        ├─ MySDK.php
        └─ SDKHelper.php
```

Adjust the namespace accordingly:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "MyPackage\\": ["src/MyPackage", "test/MyPackage"] }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the job of `autoload-dev` to separate test code from production code, so there is no need to mix the path containing `test` into `autoload`.